# How to make a CStatic control (MFC) transparent?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, dialog

My application has a start dialog with an image which fills the whole dialog. Additionaly there is a CStatic control, which displays some variable information for the user. I made the CStatic control transparent with following code:

```
HBRUSH CStartbildDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    if(pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_STATIC_INFO)
    {
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        return reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(::GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
    }
    else
        return CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
}
```

When I change the text of the static control with `GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_INFO)->SetWindowText`, the new text overlaps the old text (the old text is not deleted). I have tried to repaint the background befor calling `SetWindowText` image with `GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_BILD)->Invalidate()`, but then no info text is shown (neither the old nor the new).

Do you know how I can make the static control transparent, so that I also can override it with a new text?

Thanks for your help!

**Solution:**
Method 2 (adapted) from the [codeproject-link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/static/TransparentStaticCtrl.aspx) from Sanja worked for me.

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_INFO)->SetWindowText(tmp);
CRect rect;
GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_INFO)->GetWindowRect(&rect);
ScreenToClient(&rect);
InvalidateRect(&rect);
UpdateWindow();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct way to do transparent buttons in WINAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595618/correct-way-to-do-transparent-buttons-in-winapi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can find transparent static sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/static/TransparentStaticCtrl.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is related to the Windows API rather than MFC framework, but the concepts translate easilly:

[Correct way to do transparent buttons in WINAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595618/correct-way-to-do-transparent-buttons-in-winapi)

Your problem is that achieving transparent controls using Win32 native controls conflicts with achieving flicker free controls when repainting occurs.