# change label's text fails after set its background color

Tags: winapi, windows-10, label

In order to make the static control background transparent, I did handle the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` like this:

```
// make label transparent
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
    HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;
    SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,0,0));  
    SetBkMode(hdcStatic, TRANSPARENT);
    return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
}
```

the label is created like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Win2Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch(msg)
  {
    case WM_CREATE:
      hTab3_label =
      CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"This is my dear text!",
          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
          50, 90, 130, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 18, NULL, NULL);
      break;
      // ...
  }
}
```

the GUI is fine so far:

[image]

but when I set a new text to it from a button call, like this:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
        
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
          // ....
          case ID_TAB1_BUTTONB:
            //MessageBox(NULL, L"Click on B button", L"", MB_OK);
            SetWindowText(hTab3_label, L"This is the new text!");
            break;
        }

    break;
```

the static control gets messed up, without replace the previous text for some reason, like the image below. If I remove the `case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` the text is replaced properly. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: You've told the control to not paint a background brush, which is the only way it has to erase the old text. If your background is a solid colour, use that as the background brush rather than a null brush (e.g. `GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE)`). If your background is going to be more complex then you'll have to clear the old background yourself (by getting the control's DC and painting over it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CStatic does not invalidate every time its text is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658719/cstatic-does-not-invalidate-every-time-its-text-is-changed)

Comment: @JonathanPotter return `GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE)` instead of null brush did worke! thanks! put it as answer so that I can accept