# Is InvalidateRect() enough to ask system to redraw a static control background?

Tags: winapi, label, background-color

I need to change the font color and background color of a static control. That colors is set by handling the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message:

```
   case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;
        SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(fColor.R, fColor.G,fColor.B));  
        SetBkMode(hdcStatic, TRANSPARENT);
        if(hBrush) DeleteObject(hBruash); // free previous brush
        hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(bColor.R, bColor.G, bColor.B));
        return (LRESULT) hBrush;
    }
```

I'm calling [`InvalidateRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) like this, from a button click:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
      case BUTTONA_ID:
         InvalidateRect(hLabel, NULL, TRUE);
      break;
    }

break;
```

It this the proper way to ask to the label to be redraw and change its font and background colors?

Comment: Did you actually try it yet and see what happens? Also, why are you re-creating the `HBRUSH` on every redraw? Don't do that. Recreate the `HBRUSH` only when the values of `bColor` actually change.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It seems to work fine but as I'm learning WINAPI, I'm not quite sure if it's the proper way to do it. Oh, in my real code I didn't recreate the brush every time, I did a simplified version of my code to post here and made this mistake

Comment: Yes, you can use `InvalidateRect` to invalidate the control and redraw it. You can also use this method in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65658704/change-labels-text-fails-after-set-its-background-color).You can also refer to this link: [CStatic does not invalidate every time its text is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658719/cstatic-does-not-invalidate-every-time-its-text-is-changed)

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT I'm using `InvalidateRect()` and `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` approach, working fine. Put it as answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It this the proper way to ask to the label to be redraw and change its font and background colors?

Yes,a static control doesn't necessarily erase its background prior to drawing the text.

So you can force the control to be invalid, so that you can easily redraw the text without having to perform other additional calls.

More reference: [CStatic does not invalidate every time its text is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658719/cstatic-does-not-invalidate-every-time-its-text-is-changed)